# Speed up Compare-Object for large directory compares

Tags: powershell

Currently I'm using `Compare-Object` to compare the contents of two directories.

The directories contain a mix of subfolders, PDF files and some textfiles. The folders can contain upwards of 20,000+ files in 50,000+ folders, 1-2GB all told.

`Compare-Object` completes in about 4m30s for a compare of that size.  I tried using [this hashtable method](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2017/08/07/use-hash-tables-to-go-faster-than-powershell-compare-object/) to speed it up, but it produces a lot of false positives due to having some duplicate folder names in there (I think?).

Are there any other options to speed this thing up?

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$dir1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$dir2
)

$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

# Directories
$sourcedir = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir1 -Recurse
$destinationdir = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir2 -Recurse

# Differences
$differences = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $sourcedir -DifferenceObject $destinationdir
$differences

$output = $differences | 
          select @{l='File/Folder';e={$_.InputObject}},
              @{l='Indicator';e={$_.SideIndicator}},
              @{l='Path';e={$_.InputObject.FullName}}
$output

$sw.Stop()

"Found " + $differences.Count + " missing objects in " + $sw.Elapsed
```

Comment: Can you add details about the kinds of false positives (including exact examples) that `Compare-Object2` produces and what makes you think it's caused by "duplicate folder names"?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a hashtable like in that link because the FullName property will always be different.

Comment: Are you sure it is the comparison that takes time, not just gathering the lists of files? Would be worth checking the speed of _each operation_.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician trivial to work around, just remove their uncommon root (`$_.FullName.Substring((Resolve-Path $dir1).Length)`)

Comment: @gvee good idea... will check that out

Comment: @gvee it's definitely the Compare-Object call - takes 95% of the execution time

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen An example - running Compare-Object I get about 250 discrepancies for a pair of directories containing ~35,000 objects.  Running Compare-Object2 I get 70,000 (i.e. a discrepancy for every object in each folder).  Reading your other comment it's probably down to their uncommon roots - where is that substring line meant to go?